# Why doesn't mouse work at the boot screen while keyboards do?

Tags: boot, keyboard, mouse

As the title states, what is special about keyboards/mouse that one works at the boot screen while the other doesn't? Both of them are input devices. Both of them can be connected to PS/2 or USB interfaces.

So, why doesn't mouse work at the boot screen while keyboards do?

Comment: Boot screen? BIOS screen? Older BIOS are designed with keyboard only, but some newer BIOS do support mouse input.

Comment: @Darius: and many old openfirmware systems. Oldschool bios was a bit of a dinosaur.

Comment: Thanks Journeyman Geek :) I'm learning new things every minute staying around this site :)

Comment: I've seen a BIOS supporting mouse input as far back as 1994. @Darius

Answer (score 2):

...Basically, in the good old days where mouse wasn't too common and Keyboards were the only input devices, the BIOS was originally designed to be navigated by the keyboard.

In my opinion, The BIOS loads up the Only **Necessary** devices for you to navigate through the BIOS Interface, or for it to check/self test before booting. Of course it detects the presence of the other devices, but it doesn't load em up till you load your OS.

As your OS loads up, That's when the other devices load up.

Modern Motherboards these days However, include BIOSes that uses mouse Navigation.